# Bigcommerce Stencil declare custom front-matter variable

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce, yaml-front-matter

I would like to define a list of featured category IDs within my homepage template. Is it possible to define a custom variable in the front matter? I can't seem to get it working:

Here is the default front-matter in `templates/pages/home.html` with my custom variable, `featured_categories` at the end:

```
---
products:
    new:
        limit: {{theme_settings.homepage_new_products_count}}
    featured:
        limit: {{theme_settings.homepage_featured_products_count}}
    top_sellers:
        limit: {{theme_settings.homepage_top_products_count}}
carousel: {{theme_settings.homepage_show_carousel}}
blog:
    recent_posts:
      limit: {{theme_settings.homepage_blog_posts_count}}
featured_categories: 'testing'
---
```

Then, in the template, this line is not producing any output:

```
{{featured_categories}}
```

Why doesn't this output the value `testing`? Ultimately, I would like `featured_categories` to be an array of category ID's. Is this possible to do using front matter?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to declare a custom front matter variable as those have to be determined in the framework by BigCommerce. You can import handlebars yourself and define a variable, but it would execute client side and not server side for security reasons.

Comment: I added `"featured_categories": "testing"` to the `settings` object in `config.json`, and was then able to access it in the template via `{{ theme_settings.featured_categories`. I guess this is a good workaround.

Comment: Looks like it works with arrays too: `"featured_categories": [1,2,3]` allows me to iterate over `theme_settings.featured_categories` in the template.